# Intellij isn't finding npm scripts anymore

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea

I don't know what I changed but Intellij is not detecting the npm scripts anymore. I was creating a second tsconfig file and after that it stoped working. I created a new project and cleared the cache but IntelliJ keep saying that there is no script

Comment: Believe IntelliJ.  You're assuming something you're doing is correct that is not.  What version of IntelliJ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that `*.json` pattern is assigned to either **JSON** or **JSON5** file type in **Preferences | Editor | File types**