# IDEA 2021.2 NPM SCRIPTS : No Scripts found

Tags: javascript, vue.js, intellij-idea

I cannot find any npm scripts , but `package.json` has:

[image: no scripts found]

Comment: Did you add a run configuration for that script?

Comment: no configuration added ,  It was good before, I don't know why it unworked

Comment: it works for me 
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70777477/intellij-isnt-finding-npm-scripts-anymore

Answer (score 1):

Package.json isn't correctly recognized. Check Settings/Preferences > Editor > File types, **package.json** is probably added as a pattern to *Text* or *Auto-detect file type by content* file types .